# Set papersize for pandoc with pdfroff

Tags: markdown, pandoc, groff, troff

I'm using pandoc to convert markdown into PDFs.
When using the LaTeX PDF engine (which is the default), I can specify a different paper size with `-V geometry:a1paper`.

I want to use the pdfroff backend with `--pdf-engine=pdfroff` as it's faster and produces better output for my use case.

So how can I specify the paper size for the pdfroff with pandoc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print the roff ms [pandoc template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) with `pandoc -D ms`, you can see that it makes use of the `papersize` variable. Not sure which sizes your groff version supports, but try something like:

```
pandoc -V papersize=a4 --pdf-engine=pdfroff -o foo.pdf --verbose
```

This emits `.ds paper a4`

You can also pass options directory to groff, see [`--pdf-engine-opt`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--pdf-engine-opt).